# How do I disable console.log when I am not debugging?

Tags: javascript, debugging, logging

I have many `console.log` (**or any other console calls**) in my code and I would like to use them only
when my app is in some kind of *"debug mode"*.

I can't seem to use some kind of logger function and internally use `console.log` because then I wouldn't know what line fired it. Maybe only with a try/catch, but my logs are very general and I don't want try/catch in my code.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Production code shouldn't be logging to the console.

Comment: I came across this: http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/04/automagic-removal-of-javascript-logging.html

Comment: I think logging to console is fine if you're in a very lightweight node.js docker container

Comment: I believe a simple **regex** during the build process that removes any `console.*` is the pretty good solution, is that **regex** is robust enough

Comment: Try this https://github.com/jchnxu/guard-with-debug. Disclaimer, I am the author.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since 2014, I simply use [GULP](http://gulpjs.com/) (and recommend everyone to, it's an amazing tool), and I have a package installed which is called [stripDebug](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-strip-debug) which does that for you.

(I also use `uglify` and `closureCompiler` in production)

---

### Update (June 20, 2019)

There's a [Babel Macro](https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-macros) that automatically removes all `console` statements:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dev-console.macro

Comment: Noone will use the whole new building system **just** to deal with "console.log in production" problem.

Comment: true, but a website that doesn't use any task manager such as GULP or GRUNT is probably far behind best-practices for web development. I want to encourage people to develop for the web in the proper way, which I truly believe that without task runner will most certainly be slower to maintain.

Comment: you can also run an NPM which just does that for you if you refuse to use GRUNT or GULP...

Comment: Anyone doing serious JS code for production should  use some task runner to process the JS code, making it readable for development, and optimised for production - including stripping console.logs, comments etc. GULP and GRUNT are life savers. I'm up-voting this answer because it provides a solid solution that works in production and development.

Answer (score 61):

I would probably abuse the [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) nature of JavaScript's [logical AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) and replace instances of:

```
console.log("Foo.");
```

With:

```
DEBUG && console.log("Foo.");
```

Assuming `DEBUG` is a global variable that evaluates to `true` if debugging is enabled.

This strategy avoids neutering `console.log()`, so you can still call it in release mode if you really have to (e.g. to trace an issue that doesn't occur in debug mode).

Comment: yeah but I'll have to add this everywhere...it's lots of code :)

Comment: @vsync: Find & replace is your friend. Find 'console.log', replace with 'DEBUG && console.log'. But overriding console if debug is enabled (like in bjornd's answer), or replacing calls to console.log with a method you can easily override / replace is a neater method that requires less or no existing code edits.

Comment: `if (DEBUG) console.log("Foo.");` only two characters longer and much more readable.

Comment: `const altConsole = { ...console };
console.log = (...data) => !environment.production && altConsole.log(...data);`

Comment: @shrys, what's that?!!!

Answer (score 52):

Just replace the console.log with an empty function for production.

```
if (!DEBUG_MODE_ON) {
    console = console || {};
    console.log = function(){};
}
```

Comment: That's a hack. Your wasting computation in production

Comment: @Raynos: SO is doing it as well. http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js Look at the empty function `StackExchange.debug.log`. I do agree it's a hack, though.

Comment: @pimvdb "Big company X is doing it wrong, this means I can do it wrong"

Comment: @Raynos: No, as I said I agree about it being a hack. Just wanted to point that out :)

Comment: @Raynos Be real, calling an empty function several times is nothing in compare to the rest of the application, it's just a quick way to solve the problem.

Comment: @bjornd Depends how much you log. It adds up. It's a hack. The cost of _using this hack_ is low, but so is the cost of fixing the hack.

Comment: Yeah I see a lot of knee-jerk reactions to any extra processing from the mathematically-impaired. If you're doing 10^6 console.logs, there may still be a problem calling an empty function. Otherwise, a few hundred client-side calls to an empty function is nearly negligible.

Comment: @Raynos, "premature optimization is the root of all evil." Do you actually know any real case when this solution would noticeably degrade the performance? Have you done any benchmarks? I bet that the time spent on writing a batch script that removes all the logging (and never messes up the code) could be better invested...

Comment: Be careful. This appears to throw errors when using strict mode.

Answer (score 33):

Clobbering global functions is generally a bad idea.

Instead, you could replace all instances of `console.log` in your code with `LOG`, and at the beginning of your code:

```
var LOG = debug ? console.log.bind(console) : function () {};
```

This will still show correct line numbers and also preserve the expected `console.log` function for third party stuff if needed.

Comment: You can avoid polluting the global namespace by adding such a log function to your site's namespace.  For instance `myNamespace.log = myNamespace.DEBUG ? console.log : function(){};`.

Comment: @NickG. -- you need to use `Function::bind` like I do in my example for `console.log` to work -- otherwise you'll get a permissions exception when you try to execute it.

Answer (score 6):

One more way to disable console.log in production and keep it in development.

```
// overriding console.log in production
if(window.location.host.indexOf('localhost:9000') < 0) {
    console.log = function(){};
}
```

You can change your development settings like localhost and port.

Answer (score 3):

This Tiny wrapper override will wrap the original `console.log` method with a function that has a check inside it, which you can control from the outside, deepening if you want to see console logs and not.

I chose `window.allowConsole` just as an example flag but in real-life use it would probably be something else. depending on your framework.

```
(function(cl){
  console.log = function(){
    if( window.allowConsole )
      cl(...arguments); 
  }
})(console.log)
```

## Usage:

```
// in development (allow logging)
window.allowConsole = true;
console.log(1,[1,2,3],{a:1});

// in production (disallow logging)
window.allowConsole = false;
console.log(1,[1,2,3],{a:1});
```

---

This override should be implement as "high" as possible in the code hierarchy so it would "catch" all logs before then happen. This could be expanded to all the other `console` methods such as `warn`, `time`, `dir` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

Add a little bash script that finds all references to `console.log` and deletes them.

Make sure that this batch script runs as part of your deployment to production.

Don't shim out `console.log` as an empty function, that's a waste of computation and space.

Comment: Parsing JavaScript with batch file? Good joke!

Comment: Something like `sed -i "/console\.log/d" <filename>` would do it (GNU sed example), provided you keep all the `console.log`s on their own lines and don't have any in `if` blocks without braces.

Comment: this can be counter productive. Lots of things can go wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
if(console=='undefined' || !console || console==null) {
  var console = {
    log : function (string) {
        // nothing to do here!!
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The newest versions of chrome show which line of code in which file fired console.log. If you are looking for a log management system, you can try out [logeek](https://github.com/ImanMh/logeek) it allows you to control which groups of logs you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

```
// In Development:
var debugMode = true

// In Prod:
var debugMode = false

// This function logs console messages when debugMode is true .
function debugLog(logMessage) {
    if (debugMode) {
        console.log(logMessage);
    }
}

// Use the function instead of console.log
debugLog("This is a debug message");
```

Comment: it can't handler logs as `console.log(logMessage1, log2, log3, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

console can out put not just log but errors warnings etc.
Here is a function to override all console outputs

```js
(function () {
    var method;
    var noop = function noop() { };
    var methods = [
    'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
    'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
    'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
    'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
    ];
    var length = methods.length;
    var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

    while (length--) {
        method = methods[length];
        console[method] = noop;
    }
}());
```

Refer to detailed post here
https://stapp.space/disable-javascript-console-on-production/