# What to put in the catch block in production

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

When debugging my app I do the following.

`.catch(error => {
  console.log("error is", error);
}`

Which is is fine but what should I do in production? I don't really want to leave all these console.logs in.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do instead?

Comment: There aren't really many choices. Either you ignore the error, throw an exception, or log a message.

Comment: Then take it out--what you report to the user, and how, is up to you. If it's something that could reasonably be recovered from, like a form submit failed, you can display a message and have them try again. If it's completely out of the user's hands, send something to your back-end logging.

Comment: *Why* don't you want to leave all the log statements in?

Comment: I just think it is a bit messy and don't really want users to see the errors. Suppose I could just suppress them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500811/how-do-i-disable-console-log-when-i-am-not-debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, in production, we would use some error logging mechanism and the one I used the most [ELMAH](https://elmah.github.io/). Or implement some other logging mechanism by yourself and log it so you can check it whenever you wanted.

Comment: Could you describe how to pass client-side errors to ELMAH, or link it's relevant documentation?

Comment: I think this is a good answer lots of paid option or https://www.bugsnag.com/pricing/ where you get a free option to log basic errors.